# Move the label a few pixels up

Tags: pine-script

I am looking but I cannot find a solution to my problem.

I would like the "sale" label to be a little higher.

Is there a way to move the label a few pixels up?

Thank you very much for your answers and help.

[image]

Hello vitruvius and thank so much for your answer,

The script is like this (so there is no label but plotshape and I don't find how to add y_offset. Somes website say that's not possible)

Is it a solution ?

```
plotshape(buySignal and showsignals ? up : na, title="Buy", text="Achat", location=location.absolute, style=shape.labelup, size=size.tiny, color=color.white, textcolor=color.green, transp=0)
```

Thanks for your advices and help.

Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `label.set_y()` function to modify the y coordinate. Just come up with some algorithm.

In this example, I placed the label at `high` then you can use the `y_offset` to add some offset positive values to go up, and negative values to go down.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script", overlay=true)

y_offset = input.int(0)

l = label.new(bar_index, na)
if close >= open
    label.set_text(l, "green")
    label.set_color(l, color.green)
    label.set_y(l, high + y_offset)
    label.set_style(l, label.style_label_up)
```

Comment: Hello vitruvius and thank so much for your answer,

The script is like this (so there is no label but plotshape and I don't find how to add y_offset. Somes website say that's not possible)

Is it a solution ?

plotshape(buySignal and showsignals ? up : na, title="Buy", text="Achat", location=location.absolute, style=shape.labelup, size=size.tiny, color=color.white, textcolor=color.green, transp=0)
Thanks for your advices and help.

Have a good day.